# ngModel displays identical values for different fields

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularjs-directive

This is an Angular 5 and Firestore project. I am using a form with `[(ngModel)]` to update a document in the database. The update is successful. But the way `[(ngModel)]` displays document field values in the input boxes themselves is incorrect, e.g. the placeholders are wrong. Each input box is displaying the same field value, when they should be different. For example

In the db, my doc looks like this

```
document
  field1: document title
  field2: google
  field3: https://www.google.com
```

But my input boxes show this

`input box 1` displays `https://www.google.com`

`input box 2` displays `https://www.google.com`

`input box 3` displays `https://www.google.com`

Here is the HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of xyz | async">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <form>
        <input [(ngModel)]="x.field1" #v1>
        <input [(ngModel)]="x.field2" #v2>
        <input [(ngModel)]="x.field3" #v3>
        <button (click)="update(v1.value, v2.value, v3.value)">update</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      {{x.field1}} #### <-- THESE WORK FINE
      {{x.field2}}
      {{x.field3}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Am I missing something in the `component.ts`?

Comment: You must give a name to your inputs. And each input must have a different one.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You must give a name to your inputs.
And each input must have a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the form tag because ngmodel inside form can cause problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).